# No Firewall installed or enabled: what is blocking a specific port?

Tags: networking

I have written a small C program that implements a Modbus Master and a Slave based on the libmodbus library. This program is installed on an Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS system (A) and runs perfectly fine.

If I start one instance of my program as Modbus Slave, I can poll it locally from another instance running as Master (target = localhost:502). However, if I try polling the Slave from another device (B) on the same network, I'm getting "Could not connect to TCP port. Port is closed."

- I'm pretty sure the port is not closed but blocked, because if it were closed I shouldn't be able to use it with localhost either, right?
- The question therefore is: what is blocking port 502 on the Ubuntu system? ufw isn't even installed. Installing it and allowing connections to tcp/502 doesn't solve the problem.
- The router of the network shouldn't be the source of the problem either as another Modbus Slave device (C) can be polled on port 502 from inside and outside the network.

[EDIT]

[image]

Comment: Unless your program is running as root, it is not allowed to listen on ports lower than 1024.

Comment: Yes, I started it with sudo. However, I had the same problem when I tried port 1502.

Comment: Listen on the same port with `netcat` installed on A. If it can be reached from B, the problem is in your code, otherwise, it is in your system or your network.

Comment: Please see EDIT in my original posting. Pretty sure Ubuntu is the problem ...

Comment: What I meant was: replace your Slave on A with netcat listening on that port, using `nc -l -p 502`, and see if you can then reach the port from B.

Comment: If I do that, it seems the port is reachable (EDIT). What does that mean now? If my program runs, port 502 is reachable locally. So how can there be something wrong with the code?

Comment: Do you bind to the localhost address, or the network IP address?

Comment: Good guess! Yes, I was binding to 127.0.0.1 by mistake. I have corrected that to 192.168.0.180 and polling my Slave from any device within the network is working now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to know! Please allow me to summarize this as an answer, in case someone else comes up against this same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of the OP, debugging with `netcat` showed that the problem was not in the network, or in the Ubuntu system where the listening process was running. Specifically, the Slave process could be reached from `localhost` but not from another host in the same network.

The problem, therefore, had to be in the coding. It turned out that the socket was bound to the localhost address (127.0.0.1) instead of the IP address. Packets arriving from the network on that interface will never make it to the listening process.